# Should I worry about dd error?

Tags: linux, dvd, dd, data-transfer, cd

I'm doing back up of some cd/dvd data discs, using dd. For all discs until now I'm getting error like:

```
dd: error reading '/dev/sr0': Input/output error
2425728+0 records in
2425728+0 records out
1241972736 bytes (1.2 GB, 1.2 GiB) copied, 439.488 s, 2.8 MB/s
```

The command executed was like:

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 of=disc.iso
```

Anyway I tried to mount the iso images produced and they seem to be ok.

What's the problem?

Is that error telling me the disc wasn't correctly written?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the DD command. If it specifies a size bigger than the CD, then it is expected.

Comment: Should I something more then `dd if=/dev/sr0 of=disc.iso`?

Comment: Question edited with dd command.

Comment: Well this very command runs without errors for me...